# Is there is a non-constant function such that each point is its local minimum?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there is a non-constant real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that each point is its local minimum, i.e. its value at any point is no greater than any other value in a sufficiently small neighborhood of the point. The answer is no if continuity is assumed, see [Continuous functions that attain local extrema at every point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544495/continuous-function-that-attain-local-extrema-every-point).

If there is such a function, is its range necessarily a countable set or not?

Comment: A constant. ${}{}$

Comment: If each point is a minimum then $f(x_0)\leq f(x)$ for arbitrarily chosen $x_0$ and $x$. Switching the roles of $x$ and $x_0$, also $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$. Hence $f(x)=f(x_0)=\textrm{const}$.

Comment: What is your definition of a minimum point?  Do all the nearby function values need to be strictly greater or just no less than the value at the point in question.  In the second case, a constant function suffices.  Your idea should have suggested the constant function as something of interest.  Why didn't you pursue the idea?

Comment: @RossMillikan just the 2nd case

Comment: @Conifold You can’t simply switch them, as each point is LOCAL minimum point.

Comment: @MingweiZhang The OP does not say anything about local.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry for that. I’ll add it.

Comment: You'll get that it is locally constant by the same argument. As long as the space (I guess $\mathbb{R}$) is connected, locally constant implies globally constant by a continuity argument. There'd be a sequence of points with one value converging to a point with a different value otherwise, and it won't be locally constant at the limit point.

Comment: @Conifold I believe this argument is right, but still don’t know how to get local constant.

Comment: I am not so sure anymore. Typical arguments use continuity at some point, see [Continuous functions that attain local extrema at every point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544495/continuous-function-that-attain-local-extrema-every-point). There might be some pathological counterexamples.